# XSLT Apply potentially multiple templates to a single node depending on conditions

Tags: html, xslt

Here is my need:
I have an HTML text composed from multiple nested SPAN. 
Some of the spans include inline css. In that inline CSS, I need to transform SOME OF the style attributes into "classical" HTML, like  .
Some spans have one or many of the attributes to be replaced by HTML elements.

Here is an example input :

```
<HTML>
<SPAN>
    Some sentance including another 
    <SPAN STYLE="font-weight: bold;" >
        included bold block 
    </SPAN>
    with a tail in it and line breaks<BR/>
</SPAN>
<SPAN STYLE= "font-family: 'Helvetica';font-weight: bold;" >
    Another span with 1 attribute not to be taken into account and 1 to be
</SPAN>
<SPAN STYLE= "font-family: 'Helvetica';font-weight: bold;text-decoration:underline;" >
    Another span with two attributes to be taken into account
</SPAN>
</HTML>
```

What I would like as a result is :

```
<HTML>
<p>Some sentance including another 
    <p><b>included bold block </b></p>
    with a tail in it and line breaks<BR/></p>
<p><b>Another span with 1 attribute not to be taken into account and 1 to be</b></p>
<p><b><u>Another span with two attributes to be taken into account</u></b></p>
</HTML>
```

I thought the best way to do it would be to use the Identity Transformation and to have templates to match the attributes with conditions like :

```
SPAN[contains(@STYLE, 'font-weight: bold;')
```

and :

```
SPAN[contains(@STYLE, 'text-decoration:underline;')]
```

Here is what I tried...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN[contains(@STYLE, 'text-decoration:underline;')]">
        <xsl:element name="u">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN[contains(@STYLE, 'font-weight: bold;')]">
        <xsl:element name="b">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN">
        <!-- replacing SPAN into <p>elements -->
        <xsl:element name="p">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN/@STYLE"/>
    <!-- suppression of the old Style attribute-->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The problem is, when it runs, it only matches either one of the the  or the  
I think I mis-understand how to use the xsl:copy in the templates to ask the template to evaluate for a SPAN and to re-evaluate the other templates for the same span, but I did not succeed to have it work with or without it...

I thank you in advance for your thoughts about it.

Best regards.

Comment: You can use modes to process the same node with different templates. In XSLT 2.0 and later you also have `<xsl:next-match/>`.

Comment: Hi Marteen,
Sorry but after lots of try / fail iterations I cannot have templates with modes works with the recursion over the cases with multiple styles in a single Span.
Does anyone, by any chance, have an example of it working ?
Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here how you can do it with modes in XSLT 1.0

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN[contains(@STYLE, 'text-decoration:underline;')]" mode="u">
        <u>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </u>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN" mode="u">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN[contains(@STYLE, 'font-weight: bold;')]" mode="b">
        <b>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="u" />
        </b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN" mode="b">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="u" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN">
        <p>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="b" />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note how a template matching `SPAN[contains(...)]` has a higher priority than one just matching `SPAN`.

So, effectively you have a change of templates. For a SPAN tag, a `p` node is output, then the `b` template is called to check for bold. The `b` templates then calls the `u` template to check for underline, and this template then processes the children. You can add more templates in a similar fashion (so `b` calls `u`, then `u` calls `i`, and the `i` processes the children).

EDIT: If you wanted to avoid writing two templates for each, you could combine each pair of templates into one, like so

```
    <xsl:template match="SPAN" mode="b">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@STYLE, 'font-weight: bold;')">
                <b>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="u" />
                </b>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="u" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>
```

And if you could use XSLT 2.0, you could use priorities, and `next-match` instead, which reduces the number of templates

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN">
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN[contains(@STYLE, 'text-decoration:underline;')]" priority="8">
        <u>
            <xsl:next-match />
        </u>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN[contains(@STYLE, 'font-weight: bold;')]" priority="9">
        <b>
          <xsl:next-match />
        </b>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="SPAN" priority="10">
        <p>
            <xsl:next-match />
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, Thank you very much for that very clear explanation ! For the XSLT 1.0 version, there are two points which question me :  1) If I want to do 5 style transformations rather than two, it means that in each of them I have to call the 4 others ? I guess so, but it leads me to question 2) If the U case calls the template B and the B template calls the template U how come don't I have an "eternal loop" in the calls ?      Even if the solution works I'd love to understand that...

Comment: In answer to your question, the mode "b" templates call the mode "u" one for the same SPAN element. But the "u" template in this case, is the "end point" and it then processes the child nodes, rather than the SPAN itself, avoiding the recursion.

Comment: If you wanted an "i" template as well, you could change the "u" template to call a new template with mode "i" instead, and then the mode "i" template would do the child processing.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help and for the clarity of your explanation !